# sftp with wsl as default OpenSSH shell on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, powershell, openssh, sftp

On Windows 10 I can set the default OpenSSH shell to be wsl with the following PowerShell command.

```
New-ItemProperty `
-Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" `
-Name DefaultShell `
-Value "C:\WINDOWS\System32\bash.exe" `
-PropertyType String `
-Force
```

However, `sftp` and `scp` stop working, I immediately get `Connection closed`.  Whereas, `sftp` works just fine when PowerShell is the default OpenSSH shell.

Is it possible to have wsl be the default OpenSSH shell and also have `sftp` and `scp` continue to work?

Comment: Does your new shell accept the `-c` option, e.g. `bash -c something`? And does it recognize the "Subsystem sftp" path that's set in sshd_config?

Comment: so `sftp` works with wsl as the default shell after running `New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShellCommandOption -Value "-c" -PropertyType String -Force`.  But I can't `cd` into the wsl directories, much less have them as the starting directories when I first `sftp` in.

Comment: @Clay not true, `sftp` still not work with the `-c` default shell command option. This time I get this error while attempting sftp `Received message too long 1224764928
Ensure the remote shell produces no output for non-interactive sessions.`

Answer (score 0):

IDK, your specific issue doesn't look to be an issue anymore.

I ran into the very same kind of error, but that was because I had set `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH\DefaultShell` to  `C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe`

*wsl.exe* doesn't take a `-c` option for non-interactive commands (like *ftp-server.exe*).
It wants instead a `-e`.

I solved it by switching to `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH\DefaultShell` to `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe`, which is the value you were using 2 years ago, so I guess that, whatever the issue was back then, it might have been solved.

Maybe it has been solved by the current default value in `sshd_config`:

```
Subsystem   sftp    sftp-server.exe.
```

That `.exe` makes all the difference in the world because WSL's bash resolves commands ending in `.exe` using the Windows PATH variable instead of the linux one and maybe you did not have an sftp-server executable in your bash path back then?